# Importing JavaMail correctly

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Ok, so how do I import JavaMail? I have read at least 15 different ideas about how to go about this, and have tried moving javax.mail.jar to the top of my export list and so on. Apparently, a ClassNotFoundException is being thrown for starting a new Session, and based off of all the other posts that i've read, it should work. Here is my code:

```
package y.mail;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MailReader extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new MailReader();
    }

 public MailReader() {
     this.setSize(800, 500);
     this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     this.setResizable(false);
     this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     this.setTitle("MailReader");
     JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
     area.setEditable(false);
     area.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
     area.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
     this.add(new JScrollPane(area),BorderLayout.CENTER);
     this.setVisible(true);
     area.append("Attempting to access inbox..\n");
     Properties props = System.getProperties();
     props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
     try {
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
       Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
       store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", "myemailid@gmail.com", "password");
       Folder f = store.getFolder("INBOX");
       area.append("Connected to inbox!");
       area.append(f.getMessageCount() + "");
     } catch (Exception e) {
       area.append("===========Error===========\n");
       area.append(e.getStackTrace() + "\n");
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions [here](https://javamail.java.net/docs/README.txt) to set your CLASSPATH?

You'll find a lot of other good information in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html), including this list of [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).